# Android & PhoneGap -- Error calling method on NPObject

Tags: java, android, cordova

I'm trying to set `FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED` in my phonegap app, but only when a certain page is shown. To do so, I have a Java plugin extending from `CordovaPlugin` with the following code in the `execute` method:

```
if (action.equals("showWhenLocked")) {
    boolean showWhenLocked = args.getBoolean(0);

    if (showWhenLocked) {
        this.cordova.getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
    } else {
        this.cordova.getActivity().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
    }

    callbackContext.success();
    return true;
}
```

It gets called with `cordova.exec(null, null, 'MyPluginClass', 'showWhenLocked', [myVar])`, but on execution I get the error

```
Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject. at file:///android_asset/www/cordova-2.2.0.js:984
```

Any ideas what's causing this/what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it? If I set the flag upon creating the activity it works just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found already that this kind of error can be caused by calls that require threads that are not available. Your use of `getWindow()` tell me that this is even more likely. You are most likely accessing information locked by another thread, like the UI thread. Check out the cordova [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_plugin-development_android_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20Android) in the section about threading in the UI thread.

Comment: Thank you. I had thought about a threading problem before, but figured that I'm not using the UI thread so it should be okay --a little naive. I'll give this a try and let you know. It could take a few days, though.

Comment: I've actually seen this message a few times in the last few days, with phonegap plugins. It also happens when a function you are using throws an exception that isn't caught. The best way to find out what is really going on is to put your call in a try, catch and use `Log.d("TAG",e.toString());` to get an error report. In one case I found that my try-catch wasn't catching, so I used `Error` instead of `Exception` and found my problem.

Comment: I don't know how I didn't think of catching the error before. I'll try that too, thanks. Again, it might take a while and I apologize for this. I will definitely come back here and (if it worked) accept the answer etc.

Comment: I tried catching the error now and it's a CalledFromWrongThreadException ("Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."). Running it on the UI thread doesn't throw this error anymore, however I will still have to check whether it's actually working sometime soon.

Comment: Well guys, I promised I wouldn't forget -- and I finally had the time to finish this. Running it on the UI thread finally did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the last vote, it helps out with someone beginning on here to finally be able to vote on answers as well. I appreciate you coming back to give the final yes.

Answer (score 0):

Using:

```
callbackContext.success();
```

will explicitly call the success callback but in your case the success callback is null so that is why you get the error.

Try using:

```
callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK));
```

that way the exec call returns but the JS will check to see if there is a success callback before trying to call it.

Comment: Doesn't change anything, unfortunately. Also, I've used `callbackContext.success();` for another plugin that I call without a callback and no problems there. I changed it in both cases now, but as mentioned -- no effect.

Comment: If I comment out the `addFlags` call I don't get any errors. So I guess something's wrong with that call?

Answer (score 0):

Adding **android-support-v4.jar** to project build path and checking it's entry in **Order and Export (tab)** of Build path works for me . - Thanks, Prodeveloper